# Formula or functions to find Upper Quartile and Lower Quartile in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, quartile

I am trying to get the upper quartile, median and lower quartile in SQL Server. Is there any function or formula? Please advice - many thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need the ntile function with either 4 (which ranks all the values based on column into 4 buckets ) or 3 which ranks all values in based on a column into three buckets.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **NTILE** function with the **Over** clause ordering the data by any appropriate column in your table/